# Overriding Djangorest ViewSets Delete Behavior

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, sql-delete, django-rest-viewsets

I have defined a Model like this:

```
class Doctor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

My Serializer:

```
class DoctorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Doctor
        fields = ('id', 'name', )
```

In View:

```
class DoctorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer
```

Now, I can delete a doctor by calling the url: **'servername/doctors/id/'**, with the http method **DELETE**. However, I want to override the delete behavior for this model. I want that, when the user deletes a record, it's **is_active** field is set to **false**, without actually deleting the record from the database. I also want to keep the other behaviors of Viewset like the list, put, create as they are.

How do I do that? Where do I write the code for overriding this delete behavior?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
class DoctorViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerializer

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        doctor = self.get_object()
        doctor.is_active = False
        doctor.save()
        return Response(data='delete success')
```